# is this an acceptable use of jquery data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery data() to attach the name of a div I'd like to show when another div (`.panel_button`) is clicked. I'm doing the attaching of this div's id to the button when the document is ready. Is this an okay way to do this? Or is it too resource intensive and unprofessional-looking?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#sample_button').data('panel', 'sample_kit_container');
    $('#mail_button').data('panel', 'mail_container');
    $('#mbillboard_button').data('panel', 'mbillboard_container');

    $('.panel_button').on('click', function(){

        $('.secondary_panel').hide();
        var panel = $(this).data('panel');
        $('#' + panel).show();

    });

});
```

Comment: Seems unnecessary. I'd just use the `id`. `$("#" + this.id.replace("_button", "_container")).show();` Just standardize the pairs. Right now the `_kit` is breaking the pattern.

Comment: I don't really feel the need to add a full fledged answer to this. Yes, this is a good way to make use of datasets (esentially what `.data` uses). I'll urge you to cache your selectors though ;)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: jQuery doesn't use `dataset` for its data. It's entirely proprietary.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall How can I cache this? What's the advantage? Thanks!

Comment: I'll agree with user1689607. You could do it your way, but if you get rid of the `_kit` thingy, a simple replace would be a lot easier, more scalable and probably faster.

Comment: @user1689607 much easier. thank you.

Comment: @user1689607 Oh yeah you're right. Was confusing `.data()`'s ability to parse data attributes with the usage of datasets. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @thomas Caching your selectors is an entirely different question. Please check out [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that should work just fine.  As an alternate, you could store the actual element itself (assuming it already exists) rather than finding it each time:

```
$('#sample_button').data('panel', $('#sample_kit_container'));
$('#mail_button').data('panel', $('#mail_container'));
$('#mbillboard_button').data('panel', $('#mbillboard_container'));

$('.panel_button').on('click', function(){

    $('.secondary_panel').hide();
    var panel = $(this).data('panel');
    panel.show();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to store the actual jQuery element in the data property, so no need to do a second selection:

```
$(function(){

   $('#sample_button').data('panel', $('#sample_kit_container'));
   $('#mail_button').data('panel', $('#mail_container'));
   $('#mbillboard_button').data('panel', $('#mbillboard_container'));

    $('.panel_button').on('click', function(){

        $('.secondary_panel').hide();
        var panel = $(this).data('panel');
        panel.show();

    });

});
```

Comment: Doesn't this risk DOM cycles?

Comment: Not sure, can you explain? The selector will be cached, so I only see this as as an improvement

Comment: This is great way to use `.data()`. But I'll suggest creating variables for each of the jQuery objects, to better illustrate the reference that is stored.

Comment: I think @LightnessRacesinOrbit is referring to potential memory leaks. If one of the containers is removed from the DOM, it is still referenced in `jQuery.cache`, so it can't be cleaned up unless its corresponding button is properly discarded. IMO, `.data()` is just one big leak waiting to happen.

Comment: @user1689607 This shouldn't be an issue since the data is associated with the DOM node in memory. Once the node is removed, so is the data. At least that's how it's supposed to work ;)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: It's stored in `jQuery.cache`. If the corresponding `button` continues to exist after the `container` has been removed, the container will not be able to be garbage collected because of the continuing reference by the button. If the `button` is discarded as well, but isn't done properly, then we'll have the same issue but with no way to rectify it.

Comment: @user1689607 Ah, you mean the container. Just did a small [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/hT6sj/) to see what happens when you do that, and you're totally right, it's still in `jQuery.cache`.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: Yeah exactly. Using `.data()` is safe as long as you are *very* careful about how you dereference and destroy elements. *(Many developers are not quite so meticulous.)* Here's your [test updated](http://jsfiddle.net/hT6sj/1/) to show the difference between methods of destroying `#foo`. If you don't use jQuery to remove it, its `jQuery.cache` entry *(with the reference to `#bar`)* continues to live.

Comment: Yep that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

@thomas, in my opnion, your solution is actually better than those in the other answers.

Including the whole object inside the data attribute may not always work. For example, what if the `$('#sample_kit_container')` object doesn't exist on load, but rather ofter an ajax load.

...

Only one tiny comment! why don't you call the data object: panelId. It would be more a bit intuitive.